# Schengen visa - multiple invitation letters

Tags: schengen

Is it OK to apply for a Schengen visa with two invitation letters from two different people at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? There are no published guidelines or rules against it nor would I expect the regulations to cover it.

Note however that your itinerary must make sense. If both people vouch that you will stay at their place on the very same day, it could damage your credibility.

Finally, a letter is usually not enough, many countries require some sort of formal invitation, especially if you want it to count toward the financial requirement.

Comment: Thanks...What if the visa is rejected and then attempted to reapply a fresh visa application. Is it advisable to use multiple invitation letter?

Comment: @rick If you are refused a visa you should not reapply until you are able to address the specific issues listed in the refusal letter.

Comment: @rick I am not sure I understood what you are asking about. If the visa is rejected you need (1) to address the specific concerns mentioned in the rejection letter and (2) be very careful not to take consular officers for fools, your previous application would be recorded in their database and if you submit a completely different plan for the same period, it will further damage your credibility.